# Boa prática com seletores em css

Tags: css

Qual é a melhor prática para trabalharmos com seletores no css?

Usar

```
.menu li { }
ou 
.item {} 
.menu .item { }
ou
.menu-item { } //aqui usamos para atribuir propriedades para as <li> por exemplo
```

Como seria a melhor prática para isso ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Melhor prática, seria precisar de menos código para que tudo funcione corretamente, do qual não precisaria de muitas classes, e sim de apenas uma classe pai acessando os filhos desta forma:

```css
.menu li {
 //codigo
}
```

Assim você não precisa atribuir uma classe à sua `<li>`, você pode utilizar um caminho mais longo(mais detalhado) se desejar, por exemplo:

```css
.menu > ul > li {
 //codigo
}
```

Ps: os `>` são apenas para indicar um caminho que está sendo percorrido, não são realmente necessários, apenas para entendimento.

No seu caso, remover a classe `menu-item` da `<li>` e utilizar no CSS `.menu li` reduz código html desnecessário, se tornando uma melhor prática.

Comment: A diferença entre usar ou não `>` é que em um caso qualquer **descendente** de `.menu` que for `li` é afetado, enquanto no outro o `li` deve ser **filho** de um `ul` que por sua vez é filho do `.menu`. Só esclarecendo...

Answer (score 3):

A primeira opção me parece a melhor prática, pela seguinte razão:

1. `.menu li`

   Aqui você tem um elemento (ou tipo de elementos) específico no qual você quer atribuir um estilo a todos os seus sub-elementos do tipo `li`. Para isso, basta dar a class `menu` ao seu elemento e automaticamente todos os seus `li`s ganham o estilo desejado.
2. `.menu .item`

   Isso obriga você a adicionar a classe `item` a cada um dos seus `li`s **além de** adicionar a classe `menu`. Se você se esquecer de dar essa classe a algum item na lista, esse item terá um estilo diferente. A menos que isso seja **por design** (por exemplo, se você quiser dar destaque a algum elemento), é uma informação reduntante.
3. `.menu-item`

   Semelhante ao item acima, só te alivia de ter que criar a classe `menu`. Mas o problema dos múltiplos `li`s cada um com sua classe permanece.

P.S. Enquanto estava escrevendo isso, o @Paulo Roberto adicionou [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9816/215) que sumariza isso perfeitamente:

> Melhor prática, seria precisar de menos código para que tudo funcione corretamente